# Issue in Displaying Notification with awesome_notifications in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, awesome-notifications

I am new to flutter.I have started to create a reminder app.I am trying to call a push notification on android alarm call back.I am using **awesome_notifications**. On call back I am calling `_ringAlarm()`.I have pasted it below.
It says `D/NotificationSender( 5192): Notification created`, but nothing shows on screen.

This exception was thrown while running:

> W/System.err( 5192): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
> notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=basic_channel
> shortcut=null contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick
> defaults=0x0 flags=0x11 color=0xff9d50dd vis=UNKNOWN(2))

```
Future _ringAlarm() async {

  AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    'resource://drawable/logo.png',
    [
        NotificationChannel(
            channelKey: 'basic_channel',
            channelName: 'Basic notifications',
            channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
            defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
            ledColor: Colors.white
        )
    ]
  );

  AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then((isAllowed) {
    if (!isAllowed) {
      AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
    }
  });

  AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
        id: 10,
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        title: 'Simple Notification',
        body: 'Simple body'
    )
  );

}
```

Answer (score 9):

That means that you had some problems with your icon to solve this problem you have to add an icon under "[project]/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/" named "logo.png". [drawable position image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuQi1.png)

When initializing you must insert only the name without the extension like this

```
AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    'resource://drawable/logo',
    [
        NotificationChannel(
            channelKey: 'basic_channel',
            channelName: 'Basic notifications',
            channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
            defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
            ledColor: Colors.white
        )
    ]
  );
```

Right now the only method available is via resource

Comment: Do you know, how to make schedule notifications?

Answer (score 3):

On top of Workflop's answer, I also had to uninstall the app from my phone, then run the installation again on Android Studio.

I had the same issue when adding an image to my app. It seems to be related to the debug cache.

I also found out that the source image is extremely restricted, but somehow this is not explained in the Awesome Notifications repo. Apparently, images must be 120x120 resolution at max and contain only simple graphics, not including pasted images. It only worked for me with text and vectorial graphics.

Answer (score 0):

On top of all the answers I would also add something that is a must to actually see the icon.

in `build.gradle` file, make sure you have set `shrinkResources false` for the release/debug version you are testing, if its set to True, nothing from the above will help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).